# Apple watch stopwatch hides some numbers

Tags: apple-watch

The stopwatch on my apple watch sometimes hides part of the numbers. Why is it doing this and is there a way to stop it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have Zoom turned on (Settings -> Accessibility -> Zoom)?  If not, does any other screen do this?

Comment: Zoom is turned off. I'm not aware of any other screen doing this but I only just got the watch.